# Are the Xbox and computer versions of Civilization: Revolution compatible?

Tags: version-differences, civilization-revolution

My friends and I wanted to play Civilization: Revolution together. They both have Xbox 360s and only I have a computer.

We were wondering if it would be possible for us to play together, without me having to purchase an Xbox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no version of [Civilization 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_5) for the Xbox 360.  There is [Civilization: Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_Revolution), but it's a completely different game.

Even if there were, it is fairly rare that PC and Xbox 360 players can play multiplayer together.  I can think of perhaps a handful of games where this is the case.

So the answer is no, you can't play Civilization 5 between a PC and the Xbox 360.

Comment: Oh I meant  Civilization: Revolution, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Cyberson, there's no version of Civilization: Revolution for PC.  Additionally, I don't believe the console versions support cross platform play (ie, I don't think PS3 players can play with 360 players, and the DS game is pretty significantly different from the other two...)

Comment: To answer the "general case" question - there is no way to play any current Civilization game on a console and a PC together in some multiplayer fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could try loading up Civilization: Revolution [on an XBox 360 emulator](http://xbox360emulator.net/). As [agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86) points out, however, it's not the same as Civilization 5. I'd be flabbergasted if you had access to multiplayer content though.

Comment: Sorry I had meant Civilization: Revolution, not Civilization 5

Comment: Well in that case, give the emulator a shot and let us know what happens :)